# Cannot Pair Teenage Engineering Ortho Remote on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth 4 LE [Ortho Remote by Teenage Engineering](https://teenage.engineering/products/orthoremote) for controlling media. When attempting to pair with a Lenovo ThinkPad P14s, the device is seen in the list of available devices, but when clicked, immediately refreshes the list and fails to connect.

```
user@P14s:~$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: B0:7D:64:69:DA:79  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN INQUIRY 
    RX bytes:9176107 acl:0 sco:0 events:165290 errors:0
    TX bytes:785485 acl:0 sco:0 commands:4416 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'P14s'
    Class: 0x1c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Revision: 0x100
    LMP Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Subversion: 0x100
    Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The item showing up in the device list was the BTLE beacon... The light on the bottom of the remote was flashing, which made me think it was in pairing mode, but it wasn't. Pressed the button on the bottom for three seconds and the blinking changed from flashing white to flashing blue, and a second `ortho remote` item appeared in the list of devices available to pair with. Paired and connected fine.